# How to automatically replace a Cloud Run Job after build (CI/CD on GCP)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-cloud-run, cicd

As I didn't find anything in the [Google Cloud Run Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs)
nor on StackOverflow, I hope to find an answer here. I want to automatically replace/deploy a Cloud Run Job after a successful build.

Right now it works like this: Trigger is triggered -> Build is taking place -> Container Image in Container Registry gets created -> I have to **manually edit** the Cloud Run Job and select the latest Container Image.

I want to get rid of the latest step and automatically replace the image in that Cloud Run Job. How is that possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Before you push image to GAR, you can `docker tag` your docker image with `latest`

In Cloud Run Job, just select the image with the `latest` tag

So that every time Cloud Run Job be triggered, it would use the latest image

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the following step to your Cloud Build configuration file of the trigger after the build step:

```
steps:
  ...
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim'
    args:
      - beta
      - run
      - jobs
      - deploy
      - my-job-name
      - >-
        --image=$_IMAGE_PATH
      - '--region=$_DEPLOY_REGION'
      - '--execute-now'
    id: Launch a job
    entrypoint: gcloud
```

For more information about the deploy job cli: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/run/jobs/deploy

Answer (score -2):

You can invoke the `deploy` command like that:

```
gcloud run jobs deploy --image=<latest image> ...
```

Comment: I don't get it. I don't want to manually invoke something via the command line. Can I define this somewhere in the Cloud Run Job Settings? In the Build Trigger? Thanks!

Comment: You can invoke this line in you r CI/CD pipeline. I do nothing manually!

Comment: Could you specify where exactly? Do I need need to add a cloudbuild.yaml for that? currently, I only have a simple Dockerfile...

Comment: Oh, yes, you need a multi step CI/CD pipeline. At least create your container, push your container, deploy your container. Cloud Build is a great tool for that!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere how to this in a YAML file with `gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk`? Facing `ERROR: (gcloud.run.jobs.deploy) unrecognized arguments:`

Comment: Prefer the cloud builder:`gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud`

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks, it works 

`
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args: [ 'run', 'jobs', 'deploy',...
`